# Checking GAWK binary characters

Tags: awk

Win 7-64
Cygwin
GNU Awk 5.1.0

I'm trying to develop a program to handle both DOS an Unix formatted files. It looks like the only difference between the two at the application level is that the last character of a line in a DOS file is "\r". I can't figure out how to do a comparison.

My input looks like "w,x,y,z", where z can be "" in Unix for "\r" in DOS. The following does not work:

`if (z || z == "\r")` # check for Unix ($4) and DOS ($4 == "\r").

Comment: How about applying dos2unix in the DOS file and then comparing?

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: @Quasimodo: I would rather do programmatic detection. The dos2unix solution works correctly, so that's not the issue. But I am curious as to how to solve this problem in general, and not to look for an outside solution - bad practice. My goal is to do `if (z || z < 0x20)` but I'll settle for just having this issue resolved. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Cyrus: You might be correct. The background is that I create a csv file in LIbreOffice and attempt to manipulate it programmatically. The .csv file is output with DOS endings, and GAWK only discards the <lf> and leaves the <cr>. What I am trying to do is to generate a Wordpress compatible page w/a Table of Contents and various tables. Each table has a caption (detected when w!= "" and x = y = z = "") and a series of entries giving a book title, author, hyperlink and whether a target attribute is required (detected when w & z != ""). W/o details, detected z == "" is important to the logic.

Comment: You should ask a new question about how to solve your problem rather than asking how to implement what you think might be the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

gawk may not even see the `\r` as they can be stripped off by underlying primitives. You need to set BINMODE to make sure your script sees them. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Built_002din-Variables and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#PC-Using where it talks about:

> Under MS-Windows, gawk (and many other text programs) silently
>   translates end-of-line ‘\r\n’ to ‘\n’ on input and ‘\n’ to ‘\r\n’ on
>   output.

So you can do:

```
awk -v BINMODE=3 '
{ print "is " ( /\r$/ ? "" : "not " ) "dos" }
'
```

but even with that you can't tell on a line-by line basis if a file has DOS line-endings or not since Windows tools can generate quoted text with linefeeds in the middle, e.g. Excel would output

```
"foo","some\nother\nstuff","bar"\r\n
```

where the above is a single row in the spreadsheet if the middle cell in a spreadsheet contained a couple of linefeeds and that'd look like this and be read as 3 separate lines by gawk on a UNIX platform unless you specifically set `RS='\r\n'`:

```
"foo","some
other
stuff","bar"\r
```

So to detect if your file has DOS line-endings or not you need to search your whole input file til you find `\r\n` and even then you don't really KNOW if that's what it means - could be the data just happened to have a `\r` at the end of one line.

From your comments below I think you're trying to do something that is simply impossible.

Here's a file created on UNIX and using UNIX line endings where the final field is `bar\r`:

```
foo,bar\r\n
```

Here's a file created on Windows and using DOS line endings where the final field is `bar`:

```
foo,bar\r\n
```

As you can see there's no way to programmatically determine given just the file `foo,bar\r\n` which of the above 2 cases that means.

Comment: Well, so now I have another headache. The question here is how do I detect a terminal character which is a control character, given that gawk strips line feeds. The new headache is that I  had intended to expand the input to include text before a table, and that text may have embedded line feeds. Given the output is HTML I can just ignore the line feeds in the program. Given that it's gawk, do I have to input the entire file as a single text string and then parse it so that I can distinguish true line endings from embedded lines.

Comment: When you say linefeed you mean carriage return, right? LF is `\n` and CR is `\r` - does newlines are CRLF `\r\n` while UNIX are LF `\n` alone. To be clear, gawk doesn't strip the CR, the underlying C code on your platform that delivers strings to its callers like gawk may strip the CR but not if you call gawk with `BINMODE=3` set so it can then tell the platform code not to do that. I'm really not sure exactly what it is you're trying to do though - if you added concise, testable sample input/output to your question it'd help a lot.

Comment: Hi Ed! Wow, that is deep. So, that's you meant with "underlying primitives"? I think it might be a good idea to transfer a bit of that comment into your answer, because I had no idea what "underlying primitives" meant (and got a bit scared! :-)) but gladly found it in your comment.

Comment: @Quasímodo I don't know any more about it, I'm just trying to repeat what Arnold Robbins (gawk provider) told me a few years ago so I just added the link to the gawk manual section that discusses it.

Comment: @EdMorton: Nope. I think I mean <lf>. You showed an example where embedded <lf> where legitimate and showed that this cause an issue on input (if <lf> are used as line separators) and made a good call in saying that a <lf> w/o an accompanying <cr> was not indicative of the 'line' being either Unix or DOS.. For my application I can control the input format. This being the case I can avoid some of the corner cases you mentioned and go about my business. But, I'd still like to know why if (URL = "\r") doesn't work. ARGH, C/C++ is simpler (n this case).

Comment: You keep stating that constructs don't wok for you but none are the constructs we suggested. Quasimodo suggested `URL ~ /\r/` and I suggested `URL ~ /\r$/`. So far you've told us in your question and comments that neither of `URL == "\r"` nor `URL ~ "/\r/"` nor `URL = "\r"` nor `$4 == "\r"` work. Right, we know those wouldn't work which is why we didn't suggest them. Have you tried either of the constructs we suggested (with `BINMODE=3`) and, if so, did they work for you? I'm assuming `URL` is a line from your input, i.e. a copy of `$0`.

Comment: I've been a C programmer for almost 40 years, C++ for about 35, and awk for about 30 - whatever it is you're trying to do would not be simpler in C or C++, we just don't know yet what it is you're trying to do and you don't seem to be trying what we suggest but are trying other things instead. Please read [ask] and then update your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat -t carriage
a1^M
a2^M
$ cat -t nocarriage
a1
a2
$ gawk '/\r/' carriage
a1
a2
$ gawk '/\r/' nocarriage
```

As you can see, with `gawk` it is straightforward to check if each line has carriage-returns. Writing the octal `\015` is a possible alternative to `\r`.

Comment: Ran a test:
`      function analyze(line) {                      # fix funky things in the input line
         print "line:   ", line
         print "URL:    ", "'", URL, "'"
         print "length: ", length(URL)
         print "index:  ", index(URL, "\r")
         print "match:  ", match(URL, "/\r/")
         exit
      }
`
With results:
`URL:     ' ^M '
length:  1
index:   1
match:   0

match didn't work but index did. Any idea why?
`

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried to insert code and failed. The upshot is index(URL, "\r") worked and match(URL, "\r") worked. At least there is a usable answer. I still don't know why the "if" statement didn't work, or why I can't check a single byte containing a control character won't work correctly. If there are no thoughts by anyone in a while, I'm going to close this question (as soon as I can find out how to "close"). Sigh, I'm getting just too old.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez Don't worry, that's no easy job, I'm sure! Regarding your if test, that's not how you write it. It should be `URL ~ /\r/`. I don't understand what's the purpose of the or operator `||` there. If you say it works for `match` and `index`, I assume `URL` does have the correct content... Anyway, the hole is deep as Ed Morton states. Follow his advice, he has a solid expertise in the subject, I've just been playing with awk for some months and trying to be helpful ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on writing the regexp. The || includes a test for two conditions (poorly written as I've come to understand). For Unix input the if (URL) checks for non-null. The DOS the URL !~ /

Comment: Sorry. The URL !~ /\r/ would check for DOS. So to succeed for either one I check both. There is a way around making the same check for each line (perform a precheck in BEGIN) . But then I would like to reread the first line (don't think I can do this) and I need a way to check for the last character so that I can say if (URL == X), where X="" or X="\r". And that brings about to how do I check URL == "\r". A circly. But the workaround is dead simple. For any valid URL, length(URL) > 1 for either Unix or DOS. Took a while to get there, and I don't like it, but it works.

Comment: wrt `if (URL) checks for non-null` - if `URL` checks for the variable `URL` being empty. It's not clear how that's in any way related to what you're trying to do. wrt `I would like to reread the first line` sure you can, with some caveats. wrt `For any valid URL, length(URL) > 1 for either Unix or DOS` that's true but again it's not clear at all what that has to do with your question. Please just post a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you as it really feels like you may be going down the wrong path with whatever it is you're really trying to do.